# Using Clipboard with Xfce and TightVNC

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, vnc, xfce, tightvnc

I'm having major difficulties in getting the clipboard (copy/paste) to work over my VNC connection. Setup:

**Server:** Ubuntu 14.04 with Xfce and TightVNCServer

**Client:** Windows 8.1 with TightVNCViewer

The problem is, I can't get the clipboard working to copy/paste from the client into the server. I tried following the advice on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35030/how-can-i-copy-paste-data-to-and-from-the-windows-clipboard-to-an-opensuse-clipb) and installed autocutsel, but that didn't help either. Any advice?

Comment: [Similar question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/tightvnc-copy-paste-between-local-os-and-raspberry-pi) and [very relevant topic](https://gathering.tweakers.net/forum/list_messages/1408741).

Answer (score 11):

How did you setup `autocutsel`? I created a `xstartup` file under the `~/.vnc` directory, with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/autocutsel -s CLIPBOARD -fork
```

Then you need to make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.vnc/xstartup
```

Restart the server and you're done

Comment: First you might need to `apt-get update` and after that  `apt-get install autocutsel` ( https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/debian/jessie/autocutsel )

Comment: Add 2: You don't have to restart server if you want to allow clipboard only in current session - just call `/usr/bin/autocutsel -s CLIPBOARD -fork` in terminal and that's it.

Comment: @jave.web I can't get that to work. I have to run it without -fork in a terminal, and leave the terminal open. (I also run it with -v so that it is verbose, so I can make sure it's working.)

Answer (score 5):

For me just this two simple steps worked:

```
sudo apt install autocutsel
autocutsel -fork
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using TightVNC, but if that tool is not a requirement you could use x11vnc. I had good success sharing the clipboard with Windows machines.

On Ubuntu it should be `apt-get install x11vnc` to install it, then use `x11vnc -xkb` to start the Server. (The `-xkb` option enables the Xservers `XKEYBOARD` option, without this the clipboard sharing did not work for me)

Comment: After installing x11vnc, that is, sorry. I'm using tightvnc as a client here and clipboard works well with x11vnc for the server.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer so it is complete.  As of now, the answer, does not really answer the author's question.

Comment: Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions (not just links to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to add detail explaining how your solution addresses the OPs question.